# Pixel manipulation performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I have created a function that adds "shadow" to the content of a canvas. The algorithm for adding shadow follows these rules:

1. If the either `x` or `y` is 0, ignore.
2. If the pixel on the current pixel's top left corner is not completely transparent, set current pixel's alpha value to 0.1.

This algorithm runs from top to bottom, left to right. Here's the relevant part, where `rendered` is a canvas that already contain rendered content.

```
    function getIndex(x, y){
        return (y * width + x) * 4;
    }

    function isClear(x, y){
        var index = getIndex(x, y);
        return data[index + 3] === 0;
    }

    function isInShadow(x, y){
        if(x < 1 || y < 1)                          return false;
        if(isClear(x, y) && !isClear(x - 1, y - 1)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    var width = rendered.width, height = rendered.height,
        imgData = renderedCtx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        data = imgData.data;

    for(var x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < height; y++){
            if(isInShadow(x, y)){
                data[getIndex(x, y) + 3] = 256 * 0.1;
            }
        }
    }

    renderedCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

As you can see, this function performs per pixel manipulation and is quite slow in performance. What is a good way to improve performance, probably without checking each pixel independently?

Comment: Also, the shadow is infinite, right? So you can simply continue it diagonally to the bottom-right until an occupied pixel is encountered. Start in the bottom left corner and work the diagonals until the top right corner is reached. And again, inline everything, increment the index directly without multiplication.

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean by "Start in the bottom left corner and work the diagonals until the top right corner is reached". Are you suggesting to treat each diagonal as one line? How does that enable it to skip checking for certain pixels?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Going to test that out.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there an easy and fast way to iterate through the 2D array diagonally? It sounds good in theory but it seems difficult to implement.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle or something to test? Am curious to try a [web worker mini-library](http://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/jsWorkforce) to see if it helps cases like this.

Comment: @Sergio I have just created one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/br98aphy/). Currently it's rendering at 10~20ms on my computer, which is pretty bad if you are shooting for <16ms.

Comment: @Sergio Anyway the result doesn't need to be extremely accurate. I'm only doing per pixel manipulation because I can't think of another to do it. If there's any "hackish" way to achieve the same effect I'll take it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 just fyi I did try using a webworker to do this task. It proved to be slower in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use diagonals. The idea is to have only one pixel check, compared to two you have now:

1. find the first occupied pixel on a diagonal
2. skip to an unoccupied one
3. fill with 0.1 while unoccupied
4. repeat 1-3 until out of bounds

Considering everything should be inlined, the code would be like this:

```
var x, y, index, index0,
    len = width * height * 4,
    stride = width * 4;
    strideDia = stride + 4; // distance to the sibling pixel towards bottom-right
```

```
// walk diagonals from the bottom-left corner to the top-left corner
for (x = 0, y = height, index0 = (y * width + x)*4 + 3; --y >= 0; ) {
    index = index0 -= stride;

    while (index < len && x < width) {
        // find an occupied pixel
        while (index < len && x < width && !data[index])
            index += strideDia, x++;
        // skip to an unoccupied
        while (index < len && x < width && data[index])
            index += strideDia, x++;
        // fill with 0.1 all unoccupied
        while (index < len && x < width && !data[index]) {
            data[index] = 25; // 0.1 * 256
            index += strideDia;
            x++;
        }
    }

    x = 0;
}
```

```
// walk diagonals from the top-left corner to the top-right corner
// (0,0) is skipped as it was processed in the previous walk block
for (x = 0, y = 0, index0 = (y * width + x)*4 + 3; ++x < width; ) {
    index = index0 += 4;
    var x0 = x;

    while (index < len && x < width) {
        // find an occupied pixel
        while (index < len && x < width && !data[index])
            index += strideDia, x++;
        // skip to an unoccupied
        while (index < len && x < width && data[index])
            index += strideDia, x++;
        // fill with 0.1 all unoccupied
        while (index < len && x < width && !data[index]) {
            data[index] = 25; // 0.1 * 256
            index += strideDia;
            x++;
        }
    }

    x = x0;
}
```

Another potentially promising idea would be to use asm.js.

Comment: So I tested the code in your answer but it probably went into an infinite loop since it froze my page...

Comment: I've tested it again and indeed it's a little bit faster :)

Comment: I've inlined everything in my original code (and reordered the loops, not sure if cache misses is a thing in JS) and amazingly it reduced the running time quite significantly.

Comment: It'd be reasonable if you post your code and accept it as a solution.

Comment: I have posted my code however your answer will stay as marked as solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is my attempt of optimizing the performance of the loop:

```
var width = rendered.width, height = rendered.height,
    imgData = renderedCtx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
    data = new Uint8Array(imgData.data.buffer),
    arrayWidth = width * 4, arrayHeight = height * 4;

for(var y = 0; y < arrayHeight; y+=4){
    for(var x = 0; x < arrayWidth; x+=4){
        if(x > 0 && y > 0 && !data[y * width + x + 3] && data[(y - 4) * width + x - 1]){
            data[y * width + x + 3] = 25;
        }
    }
}

renderedCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

I eliminated all function calls since calling a separate function requires more operations, and the loops are also flipped to avoid possible cache misses. The result is that the loop's running time is greatly decreased, making `getImageData` the most expensive operation in this function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple optimization that most programmers fail to notice:

```
if (...)  return true  else  return false;
```

==>

```
return (...);
```

Instead of looking at every pixel, only look at each diagonal from upper left toward the south-east.  (Assuming 0,0 is in the north-west.)  It seems that once you hit a clear spot, the rest of the diagonal line gets an alpha of 256*0.1?  Take advantage of that and plow down the diagonal.